# Python: Why does this command work when I didn't import command

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a Python GUI for the first time to plot some data, and have imported the following modules/commands to do so

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.ttk import *

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
```

Searching the internet, I found some code that worked to get my plot embedded in the GUI:

```
fig = figure()
fig.add_subplot(111).pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap = get_cmap('BuPu'))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
```

My question is why does pcolormesh work in the second line above when I didn't import that command from matplotlib.pyplot? I'm new to Python, and I'm sure I'm missing something, but if I wanted to use the pcolormesh command in the past, I had to import it. Thanks.

Comment: No, this is just a method from figure. All methods are imported (with some name-mangling exceptions for those starting with double underscore).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've only had a couple days with Python, so I'm trying to figure stuff out still.  Can you elaborate a bit more? I understand why figure() works, because I imported that directly with matplotlib.pyplot import figure . Are you saying by doing that, I implicitly imported other methods from matplotlib.pyplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function calls created objects and those objects have methods. You don't need to import those methods as they are attached directly to the object. They are different from importing a function as you don't have direct access to those methods: they can only be accessed from the object.

when you set `fig = figure()`, you created an object.  If you `print(repr(fig))` you'll see something like this.

`'<matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x000000000784F208>'`

so `fig` is a `Figure` object. This objects comes with some methods and properties attached to it. You can get a list of all the methods using `dir(fig)` (it's a long list, so I won't print it here).

`fig.subplot(111)` calls the `subplot` method attached to your `fig` object. It returns a new object (an `AxesSubplot`).  **That** object has a method attached to it called `pcolormesh`. If you want to play around with that object, you can do this.

```
ax = fig.subplot(111)
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap = get_cmap('BuPu'))
print(repr(ax))
```

In addition to doing your stuff, this will print `<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x8996f28>`.

I remember being similarly confused by matplot.pyplot when I first started out because you can often do nearly identical things with a function (`matplotlib.pyplot.pcolomesh`) and as a method of an object (in the above example, `ax.pcolormesh`). They mention it in the API explanation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_summary.html#the-pyplot-api) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_summary.html#the-object-oriented-api).

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: One last thing. How would I add a colorbar? I see that colorbar is an available method of fig.subplot(111).pcolormesh using the dir command. So would I just add a .colorbar() to the end of fig.add_subplot(111).pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap = get_cmap('BuPu'))?

Comment: i'm not sure, but your best bet is to check the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar) or just try it and see what happens. It looks like `colorbar` is a method of the `fig` object and needs to be passed the specific image or contours that it's being applied to.